# How to find Averages of HH:MM (time of day) in R?

Tags: r, excel, time, average, mean

My dataset has a record of onset of a certain bat behavior through different nights. I want to find the average of these times which are in hh: mm (24hr clock) format.

```
Onset:
23:42,
21:40,
21:20,
21:30,
22:15,
23:40,
23:30,
02:10,
00:40,
01:35,
01:28,
01:00,
01:00,
00:55,
01:35.
```

For possible `R` solution, sample data:

```
onset <- c("23:42","21:40","21:20","21:30","22:15","23:40","23:30",
           "02:10","00:40","01:35","01:28","01:00","01:00","00:55","01:35")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in 1 line with `lubridate`:

```
seconds_to_period(mean(period_to_seconds(hm(Onset))))
```

which yields

> ```
> [1] "11H 12M 0S"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Not a one liner (code below adjusted to address night vs. morning issue raised by OP in comments):

```
onset <- c("23:42","21:40","21:20","21:30","22:15","23:40","23:30",
           "02:10","00:40","01:35","01:28","01:00","01:00","00:55","01:35")

library(tibble)

onset.df <- t(data.frame(strsplit(onset, ":"), stringsAsFactors=F))
colnames(onset.df) <- c("hours", "minutes")
onset.df <- as_tibble(onset.df)
onset.df$hours <- as.numeric(onset.df$hours)
onset.df$minutes <- as.numeric(onset.df$minutes)
onset.df$minutes.fraction <- onset.df$minutes/60
onset.df$hours.fraction <- onset.df$hours+onset.df$minutes.fraction
mean(onset.df$hours.fraction)
[1] 11.2

# alternative approach to account for night / morning
onset.df$hours <- ifelse(onset.df$hours < 12, 
                         onset.df$hours+24, onset.df$hours)
onset.df$hours.fraction <- onset.df$hours+onset.df$minutes.fraction
onset.df
# A tibble: 15 x 4
   hours minutes minutes.fraction hours.fraction
   <dbl  <dbl           <dbl         <dbl>
 1  23.0    42.0            0.700           23.7
 2  21.0    40.0            0.667           21.7
 3  21.0    20.0            0.333           21.3
 4  21.0    30.0            0.500           21.5
 5  22.0    15.0            0.250           22.2
 6  23.0    40.0            0.667           23.7
 7  23.0    30.0            0.500           23.5
 8  26.0    10.0            0.167           26.2
 9  24.0    40.0            0.667           24.7
10  25.0    35.0            0.583           25.6
11  25.0    28.0            0.467           25.5
12  25.0     0              0               25.0
13  25.0     0              0               25.0
14  24.0    55.0            0.917           24.9
15  25.0    35.0            0.583           25.6
onset.mean.raw <- mean(onset.df$hours.fraction)
onset.mean.format <- ifelse(onset.mean.raw >= 24, 
                            onset.mean.raw-24, onset.mean.raw)
onset.mean.format.hour <- round(onset.mean.format, 0)
onset.mean.format.minutes <- round((onset.mean.format-onset.mean.format.hour)*60, 0)
paste("Average time of onset:", onset.mean.format.hour, "hours and",
       onset.mean.format.minutes, "minutes")
[1] "Average time of onset: 0 hours and 0 minutes"
```

I'm just using `tibble` to get rid of row names and make the table easier to read in the `R` console.

Comment: The mean time "11.2" or "11:12" is logically a time point in the morning. This is misleading since all the recorded times were in the nights between 21:00 to 03:00. Could this 11:12 be considered as 23:12?. If yes then where did the math go wrong?

Comment: @BaheerathanM See revised answer. If the hour is less than 12, you can just add 24 to it. The, if you get an answer like 25, it can be understand as 1 in the morning.

Comment: @BaheerathanM Answer updated again.

Answer (score 1):

The rarely used `as.difftime` would be handy here, to match @Hack-R's result:

```
mean(as.difftime(dat$Onset, format="%H:%M", units="hours"))
#Time difference of 11.2 hours
```

Since the times lap over the end of the day though, I think you need to get trickier:

```
out <- as.numeric(as.difftime(dat$Onset, format="%H:%M", units="hours"))
mean(ifelse(out < 12, out + 24, out))
# [1] 24
```

...interpretable as midnight.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to do the computation. The only problem is that the method `mean.POSIXct` needs its argument to be of class `"POSIXct"` or `"POSIXt"`. Since you only have HH:MM, the function does the coercion for you.

```
meanHour <- function(h, format = "%H:%M"){
  hh <- as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), h), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
  hmean <- mean(hh)
  format(hmean, format = format)
}

meanHour(Onset)
#[1] "11:12"
```

**Edit.**

After the comments by the OP, I have written a function that handles hours past midnight.

```
meanHour2 <- function(h){
  f <- function(x){
    x[1] <- ifelse(x[1] < 12, x[1] + 24, x[1])
    60*x[1] + x[2]
  }

  hh <- strsplit(h, ":")
  hh <- lapply(hh, as.integer)
  hh <- sapply(hh, f)
  hmean <- mean(hh)
  H <- hmean %/% 60
  M <- hmean %% 60
  sprintf("%02d:%02d", H, M)
}

meanHour2(h)
#[1] "24:00"
```

**Data.**

```
Onset <- scan(what = character(), 
          text = "23:42, 21:40, 21:20, 21:30, 22:15, 23:40, 
                  23:30, 02:10, 00:40, 01:35, 01:28, 01:00, 
                  01:00, 00:55, 01:35",
          sep = ",")
```

Comment: The mean time "11:12" is logically a time point in the morning. This is misleading since all the recorded times were in the nights between 21:00 to 03:00. Could this 11:12 be considered as 23:12?. If yes then where did the math go wrong?

Comment: (21:00 + 03:00)/2 == 24:00/2 == 12:00. I too had noticed that but then I saw the times past midnight. The result is 11:12 AM.